# Fragment page is not scrolling in android

Tags: android, xml, fragment, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I have one fragment but its not vertically scrolling . My XML code is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:background="#E6E6E6">
 <!-- Top Sliding Banners -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="220dip" >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
        <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="bottom|left"
            android:padding="10dip"
            />
     </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Trending"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
    </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popular_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Popular"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/popular_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/popular_textview"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
 </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
     android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/featured_textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:text="Featured"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/featured_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/featured_textview"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried all solution of stackoverflow.My code have three recyclerview and they work fine .Only problem is than page is not vertically scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using NestedScrollView as parent tag for this layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

remember to keep only one direct child for nestedScroll view.

Comment: Thanks .This woked for me. :-)